# Memory allocation to functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, static

I am still a C++ newbie. Just came to read that the static member function of a class is not object specific - there is a single copy of the member functions for all the objects.

Now two questions arise in my mind :

1. What is the difference between an ordinary function and a static function "in terms of memory allocation only" ?
2. What if the member function contains some local variables ? In that case the function "should" have a separate copy of that variable - specific to the object invoking the function... How is this problem solved in C++ ?

Thanks !

Comment: I would like to correct my question : By "member function" in my 2nd question, I mean "static member function"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the difference between an
> ordinary function and a static
> function "in terms of memory
> allocation only" ?

Nothing.  A static function is just like a global function except for the scope.

Even for non-static member functions, there's no extra memory required.  The member function `int C::f(int arg1, int arg2)` is just syntactic sugar for something like `int C__f(C* this, int arg1, int arg2)`.

> What if the member function contains
> some local variables ? In that case
> the function "should" have a separate
> copy of that variable - specific to
> the object invoking the function...

There's a copy of the local variables for *each invocation* of the function (unless they're `static`).  This is why recursion in possible in C++.

> How is this problem solved in C++ ?

Function calls are based around "stack frames".  A stack frame consists of:

- The arguments to the function (including the implicit `this` if applicable).
- Any other non-`static` local variables in the function.
- The "return address", which tells the processor where to resume execution once the function is done.

Whenever a function is called, a stack frame is created.  When the function returns, the stack frame is destroyed.  If a function is called recursively, each level of recursion gets its own stack frame.   For example, if you have

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Then when you call `factorial(3)`, a stack frame gets created like so:

```
------------------------ stack pointer (SP)
n = 3
RA = <in main()>
```

When the recursive call is made to `factorial(2)`, an additional frame is added to the top of the stack

```
------------------------ SP
n = 2
RA = <in factorial()>
------------------------
n = 3
RA = <in main()>
```

Another recursive call is made, to `factorial(1)`.

```
------------------------ SP
n = 1
RA = <in factorial()>
------------------------
n = 2
RA = <in factorial()>
------------------------
n = 3
RA = <in main()>
```

This is the base case for the recursion, and the return value of 1 is stored in a register.  The function call being complete, the top stack frame is destroyed, and execution continues at saved return address.

```
------------------------ SP
n = 2                                      
RA = <in factorial()>
------------------------
n = 3
RA = <in main()>
```

Now, the call to `factorial(2)` can compute its return value (2), and another stack frame can be destroyed:

```
------------------------ SP
n = 3
RA = <in main()>
```

Finally, we can compute the result of the original function call (6), and destroy this stack frame too.

Comment: I would like to correct my question : By "member function" in my 2nd question, I mean "static member function"

Comment: Stack frames work the same way for static and non-static member functions.  The only difference is whether `this` is one of the local variables.

Answer (score 4):

1. no difference
2. local variables are created and destroyed on the stack *per invocation* of the function

Comment: If the function itself has only 1 copy, how can it have multiple copies of its variables on the stack ?

Comment: There's a stack frame for each INVOCATION of the function.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would find it very unlikely that there would be a difference
2. Seems like you should read a bit about the difference between **heap** and **stack allocations**. This gives a good idea about how memory works at a low, but still high level. Sorry i can't be more helpful right now.

edit: too slow :)

Answer (score 0):

1. There really isn't that much of a difference. Both are stored in memory only once, when a non-static method is called, a pointer to the current object (the this pointer) is pushed onto the stack (or stored in ECX depending on your compiler) in addition to all of the function's parameters. A static function doesn't need an instance of a class, so it is just called like a regular C function.
2. Same way as in C, with the call stack.